# How to add static data and then in real-time in GraphView in Android?

Tags: android, graph, real-time, android-graphview, android-thread

I need to add data from a array and then add data in real time. I can do the 2 things separately, but when I want to do everything together, the application closes before it starts.

The idea is to show data that I receive through Bluetooth and as I receive 5 series the idea is to be able to visualize the 5 at any time. What I want to do then is to graph the data that already arrived to me and to add the ones I am receiving, then I can go to see the different series by resetting the graph and loading it with the values of another series.

I attach the code.

Thank you very much.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
private LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
private int lastX = 0;

double[] x= new double[10];
double[] y= new double[10];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // we get graph view instance
    values();
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;
    GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    // data
    series = new LineGraphSeries<>(data());
    graph.addSeries(series);
    // customize a little bit viewport
    Viewport viewport = graph.getViewport();
    viewport.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    viewport.setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    viewport.setMinY(0);
    viewport.setMaxY(10);
    viewport.setMinX(0);
    viewport.setMaxX(30);
    series.setThickness(1);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // we're going to simulate real time with thread that append data to the graph
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // we add 100 new entries
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        addEntry();
                    }
                });

                // sleep to slow down the add of entries
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // manage error ...
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

// add random data to graph
private void addEntry() {
    // here, we choose to display max 10 points on the viewport and we scroll to end

    series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastX++, RANDOM.nextDouble() * 10d), false, 1800);
}

public DataPoint[] data(){
    DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[10];     //creating an object of type DataPoint[] of size 'n'
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        DataPoint v = new DataPoint(x[i],y[i]);
        values[i] = v;
    }
    return values;
}

private void values(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    x[i]=i;
    y[i]=i;
    }
}

}
```